# Sum from TR with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have for example:

```
<table>
    <tr class="main"><td>test | sum:<span class="sum_main"> </span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">2</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">6</span></td></tr>
    <tr class="main"><td>test | sum:<span class="sum_main"> </span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">2</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
    <tr class="main"><td>test | sum:<span class="sum_main"> </span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">2</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">8</span></td></tr>
</table>


table td {
   border: solid 1px black;
   padding: 4px;
}

.main {
background-color: #cc99ff;
}


$(".sum_main").val( $(".sum_main").val() + $(".sum_main").val() + $(".sum_main").val()); // ???????
```

**LIVE EXAMPLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/dZLg6/

How can sum from class sum_sub and show this in sum_main with jQuery and function for example each?
This example should show me:

```
<table>
    <tr class="main"><td>test | sum:<span class="sum_main">13</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">2</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">6</span></td></tr>
    <tr class="main"><td>test | sum:<span class="sum_main">7</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">2</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
    <tr class="main"><td>test | sum:<span class="sum_main">20</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">2</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">8</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to iterate over all the `.sum_main` elements. Inside the loop you can get the text from each of the following `.sum_sub` elements (until the next `.main` row) and maintain a running total:

```
$(".sum_main").each(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).closest("tr").nextUntil(".main").each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).find(".sum_sub").text(), 10);
    });
    $(this).text(total); 
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/dZLg6/4/).

**Update**

As noted in the comments, it may be worth checking that `parseInt` actually returns a number. If it doesn't, it will return `NaN`, and adding that to our total will make the total `NaN`. We can do this with the [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function. Something along these lines:

```
var num = parseInt($(this).find(".sum_sub").text(), 10);
if(!isNaN(num)) {
    total += num;
}
```

Comment: just for fail-safe: you should check with `IsNaN`

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair - Good point, it may well be worth checking. I've updated the answer. Note, however, that it's `isNaN` (with a lower-case `i`).

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;
$(".sum_sub")).each(function(sum) {
sum += parseInt($.trim($(this).html()),10);
  });
alert(sum);
```

Comment: DANGER!! (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/1kc6b02f.aspx): "radix
Optional. A value between 2 and 36 indicating the base of the number contained in numString. If not supplied, strings with a prefix of '0x' are considered hexadecimal and strings with a prefix of '0' are considered octal. All other strings are considered decimal." - rather use `parseInt('...', 10)`. Besides that, check the int with `IsNaN` to be fail-safe!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/dZLg6/1/

```
$("tr.main").each(function(){
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).nextUntil(".main").each(function(){
        sum += parseInt($(this).find(".sum_sub").text(), 10)
     });
    $(this).find(".sum_main").text(sum);
})
```

Comment: just for fail-safe: you should check with `isNaN`

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmsGS/

Code:

```
var sumSpan = null;
$('span').each(function() {
    var tr = $(this);
    if(tr.hasClass('sum_main')) sumSpan = tr;
    else if(tr.hasClass('sum_sub')) {
        if(sumSpan != null) {
            sumSpan.text( parseInt(sumSpan.text(), 10) + parseInt(tr.text(), 10) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DANGER!! (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/1kc6b02f.aspx): "radix
Optional. A value between 2 and 36 indicating the base of the number contained in numString. If not supplied, strings with a prefix of '0x' are considered hexadecimal and strings with a prefix of '0' are considered octal. All other strings are considered decimal." - rather use `parseInt('...', 10)`. Besides that, check the int with `IsNaN` to be fail-safe!

Answer (score 1):

If you [group your rows](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) using `tbody`s

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="main"><td>test | sum:<span class="sum_main"> </span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">2</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">6</span></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="main"><td>test | sum:<span class="sum_main"> </span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">2</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="main"><td>test | sum:<span class="sum_main"> </span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">5</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">2</span></td></tr>
      <tr class="sub"><td>test | sum <span class="sum_sub">8</span></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

then you can easily sum things

```
$.each(myTable.find('tbody'), function (_, tbody) {
  tbody = $(tbody);
  var sum = 0;
  $.each(tbody.find('.sum_sub'), function (_, sum_sub) {
    sum += +$(sum_sub).text();
  });
  tbody.find('.sum_main').text('' + sum);
});
```